# Computing BIC and other methods to find most likely K cluster

Tags: bayesian, clustering, population, bic, genetics

I have recently been diving into the world of population genetics and still remain with some questions when trying to conclude what the most likely value of K for my dataset would be.

To give you some context, I have been trying to identify population structure in Thornback ray using 1838 samples with 5904 SNPs per individual in fastStructure (Raj et al., 2014). I have generated multiple results regarding the most likely value of K. However, I am still figuring out whether I am on the right tract. Please see the results below:

**fastStructure chooseK.py script:**
Identifies an optimum K between 2 and 4

**StructureSelector output and BIC**
[image: To me it looks like my most likely value of K would be at 3. However, the Y-axis of StructureSelector output confuses me]

To me it looks like my most likely value of K would be at 3. However, the Y-axis of StructureSelector output confuses me.

To clarify - I am using K-means clustering to identify whether subpopulations of this ray species are present. However, I find it difficult to interpret the results.

So, is the value of K indicating the amount of clusters and thus subpopulations present? Then, why is is the Y-axis indicating two 'clusters' at K = 3, 6, and 9? What does this mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What confuses you?

Comment: Generally the concept of a "cluster" is not uniquely defined, and different clusterings (including with different numbers of clusters) can be legitimate on the same data set. Whether a certain number of clusters is good or not can only be decided in connection with a definition/description of what kind of clusters you are looking for, what the clusters  are then used for, and how you'd interpret them.